# Python 3 rstrip()

Tags: python-3.x

I'm learning the Python Essentials 2 from Python Insitute at the moment. So I'm a noob.

Could someone explain to me why `print("cisco.com".rstrip(".com"))` would only return "cis"?

I understand `rstrip()` will remove the characters in the argument from the end of the string "cisco.com".

In this case, the argument to rstrip() is ".com", so the method will remove the characters ".com" from the end of the string "cisco.com". Wouldn't the result should be the string "cisco"? >.<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`rstrip()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_rstrip.asp) removes all trailing characters given as argument.

So, in your example, `rstrip(".com")` will remove `.`, `c`, `o`, `m`, starting from the right, and stops as soon as it finds a character that is not in the list.

Starting from right, `m`, `o`, `c`, `.`, `o`, `c` are removed. Then `s` is not in the list, and `rstrip` stops.

If you want to remove only `.com`, you need to use [`removesuffix()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-removesuffix/).

```
>>> print("cisco.com".removesuffix(".com"))
cisco
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip):

> Return a copy of the string with trailing characters removed. The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed. If omitted or None, the chars argument defaults to removing whitespace. **The chars argument is not a suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped**

So the rtrim will remove all characters from the argument regardless of the order of the argument until no more characters match:

```
>>> print("cisco.com".rstrip("c")) # Last character "m" is not in the argumentlist, so nothing will happen
cisco.com
>>> print("cisco.com".rstrip("o.mc"))
cis
>>> print("cisco.com".rstrip("m"))
cisco.co
>>> print("cisco.com".rstrip("mo"))
cisco.c
>>> print("cisco.com".rstrip("moc"))
cisco.
>>> print("cisco.com".rstrip("moc."))
cis
```

If the order matters, use [removesuffix](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removesuffix)

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because it is removing any character that trails as long as it is one of the following ".", "c, "o", "m". It doesn't matter what order they are in. Since cisco.com has all of those characters after the 3rd character (s), it is removing them. rstrip doesn't removing a trailing substring. for example. Doing `print("acoco.com".rstrip(".com"))` would give an output of "a".

If you need a solution for just the given example you could try the following:

```
delimiter="." 
print("cisco.com".split(delimiter, 1)[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"cisco.com".rstrip(".com")
```

The call of `.rstrip()` while passing a string as a parameter will return a string where the last characters of the caller string are removed until it's ending with a character that differs from all characters of the input or empty. The parameter is `".com"` and the string upon which we call the method is `"cisco.com"`.

While I do not know how this method was actually implemented, I will provide an explanatory algorithm that yields an equivalent result. **Don't assume that the following is what actually happens, but you need to understand that something equivalent happens that yields the same result:**

1. The last character of "cisco.com" is m, which is a character of ".com", so we remove it and proceed evaluating the new last character
2. The last character of "cisco.co" is o, which is a character of ".com", so we remove it and proceed evaluating the new last character
3. The last character of "cisco.c" is c, which is a character of ".com", so we remove it and proceed evaluating the new last character
4. The last character of "cisco." is ., which is a character of ".com", so we remove it and proceed evaluating the new last character
5. The last character of "cisco" is i, which is a character of ".com", so we remove it and proceed evaluating the new last character
6. The last character of "cisc" is c, which is a character of ".com", so we remove it and proceed evaluating the new last character
7. The last character of "cis" is s, which is not a character of ".com", so the result is `"cis"`

**Again, this is not necessarily the actual implementation of the `rstrip` method, the above serves the purpose of understanding intuitively what this method is about and what results it will have.**